# Add an aggregate of column to existing spark streaming dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I need to add an aggregated column to a spark streaming dataframe.

My spark dataframe has this form:

```
+-----------+---------+
| Timestamp | User_id |
+-----------+---------+
| 123343222 |      01 |
| 121212122 |      02 |
| 121212121 |      03 |
+-----------+---------+
```

I need to have a spark streaming dataframe of that form:

```
+-----------+---------+--------------+
| Timestamp | User_id |  Array_UID   |
+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 123343222 |      01 | [01]         |
| 121212122 |      02 | [01, 02]     |
| 121212121 |      03 | [01, 02, 03] |
+-----------+---------+--------------+
```

After the creation of this spark streaming dataframe I need to process it with a udf that needs to take in consideration all the user id already arrived.

I tried to collect the id using this code:

```
presenceDF = dfStreaming\
         .groupBy(
            window("timestamp", "30 minutes", "30 minutes"), \
         ).agg((F.collect_set(F.col("User_id"))).alias("Array")) \
```

The result is the following:

```
+---------+--------------+
| Window  |    Array     |
+---------+--------------+
| W1      | [01]         |
| W2      | [01, 02]     |
| W3      | [01, 02, 03] |
+---------+--------------+
```

I need to have also the information of the latest User_id arrived, that's because this form doesn't work for me. 
Is there a way to add the Array column to the streaming dataframe, preserving the original columns? 
In static dataframe you can achieve that making a self join, but here is not possible.

Any help?